# Sound card for raspberry pi?

Tags: audio, analog-to-digital

Can anyone recommend the best way of recording audio input? Are there any "sound cards" for Raspberry Pis?

Edit: I've seen Linux software for ham radio. And see that Debian Wheezy has a whole lot of apps for radio. The problem is trying to code/decode the sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw the [Wolfson audio card](http://nz.element14.com/wolfson-microelectronics/wolfson-audio-card/audio-card-for-use-with-raspberry/dp/2347264) today. It looks like the kind of thing i wanted.

It has both stereo line in and line out.

Comment: Be aware that the Wolfson card will not work with the new B+ board.

Comment: However it is now over a year later and having been acquired by Cirrus Logic there is the [new version](http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/cirrus_logic_audio_card) for B+ and 2 Bs.

Answer (score 1):

if you do a search on here for Audio input, there are a number of ways you can get audio recorded to your raspberry Pi,

for example:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=audio+input

[Suitable microphone for IO pins](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11639/suitable-microphone-for-io-pins)

[Can I get audio input through the GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/can-i-get-audio-input-through-the-gpio)

or

[USB microphone recording input and audio output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3648/usb-microphone-recording-input-and-audio-output)

as an example of someone who is using a USB sound card.

Answer (score 1):

I use a USB sound card on my Raspberry Pi. I got a cheap one on ebay that has just one each input and output 3.5mm jack port.

Answer (score 1):

I picked up a nice little USB sound card from Amazon for less than $2 US ([Eastvita 7.1 Channel USB External Sound Card Audio Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MN1LTQ))

[Here is some help I got setting it as the default sound card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/usb-card-as-my-default-audio-device)

Best $2 I ever spent.